# How to divide the data in multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

As the picture, I have a multi-index dataframe named `"overall_zx"[78]`.

There are sales and volumns for `YTD2017/YTD2018/YTD2019`. Now I want to calculate the price (sales divide volumns by individual `YTD`). I found the way to calculate the price as `[79]`, but I don't know how to combine it in `overall_zx` this table.

Otherwise, is there any way can divide them directly? just like the sigle hierarchy dataframe. For example:

```
df['price']  = df['sales'] / df['volumns']
```

(In `multi-index`, this code doesn't work)

[image: Dataframe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with new `MultIndex` DataFrame by selecting by double `[]` and `rename` to same new name, here `price`:

```
df1  = (df.join(df[['sales']].rename(columns={'sales':'price'}) / 
                df[['volumns']].rename(columns={'volumns':'price'})))
```

Another idea with reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and 
[`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

For new column is use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for one line solution:

```
df1 = df.stack().assign(price = lambda x: x['sales'] / x['volumns']).unstack()
```

What is same like this alternative:

```
df1 = df.stack()
df1['price'] = df1['sales'] / df1['volumns']
df1 = df1.unstack()
```

Data borrow from @Valdi_Bo:

```
print (df1)
  volumns                    sales                        price             \
  YTD2017 YTD2018 YTD2019  YTD2017  YTD2018  YTD2019    YTD2017    YTD2018   
A   212.0   220.0  226.16  3654.04  4163.87  4695.12  17.236038  18.926682   
B    17.5    18.5   18.57   234.84   274.47   298.90  13.419429  14.836216   
C    18.5    14.5   12.66   213.02   191.14   177.46  11.514595  13.182069   


     YTD2019  
A  20.760170  
B  16.095854  
C  14.017378
```

Answer (score 2):

For my test I used the following DataFrame (using Latin characters
as column names and index):

```
   Volume                     Sale                  
  YTD2017 YTD2018 YTD2019  YTD2017  YTD2018  YTD2019
A   212.0   220.0  226.16  3654.04  4163.87  4695.12
B    17.5    18.5   18.57   234.84   274.47   298.90
C    18.5    14.5   12.66   213.02   191.14   177.46
```

My first observation is that `df.Sale / df.Volume` alone **does** work,
so let's save the result in an auxiliary DataFrame (*df2*).
So far we have:

```
     YTD2017    YTD2018    YTD2019
A  17.236038  18.926682  20.760170
B  13.419429  14.836216  16.095854
C  11.514595  13.182069  14.017378
```

This result can not be joined to the original *df*, because *df* has a
**MultiIndex** as columns, whereas *df2* has an "ordinary" index.

But we can **add** the missing index level to columns in *df2*:

```
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Price'], df2.columns])
```

Now *df2* contains also a **MultiIndex** on columns:

```
       Price                      
     YTD2017    YTD2018    YTD2019
A  17.236038  18.926682  20.760170
B  13.419429  14.836216  16.095854
C  11.514595  13.182069  14.017378
```

So now there is no obstacle to join these 2 DataFrames:

```
df = df.join(df2)
```

getting:

```
   Volume                     Sale                        Price             
  YTD2017 YTD2018 YTD2019  YTD2017  YTD2018  YTD2019    YTD2017    YTD2018    YTD2019 
A   212.0   220.0  226.16  3654.04  4163.87  4695.12  17.236038  18.926682  20.760170 
B    17.5    18.5   18.57   234.84   274.47   298.90  13.419429  14.836216  16.095854 
C    18.5    14.5   12.66   213.02   191.14   177.46  11.514595  13.182069  14.017378
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is concise and easy to understand.